# Why is my page overflowing on the right?

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm using a variation of Matthew James Taylor's Holy Grail 3-column liquid layout. It was working perfectly for me when my doctype was XHTML. When I transitioned to HTML5, however, it started overflowing to the right. The visible area still renders fine, but the browser shows a horizontal scroll bar when it shouldn't and there's excess whitespace to the right of the page.

My web site is here:
[Western Wake Farmers' Market](http://westernwakefarmersmarket.org/) | [Link to CSS](http://westernwakefarmersmarket.org/App_Themes/Normal/Normal.css)

Any insights as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it happened - I have no idea, and I'm not going to look at it unless you ask me to.

The `ul` inside `#header` is too wide, thanks to the combination of `width: 100%`, and (as @zerocrates stated before I did), the padding.

How to fix it:

- Remove `width: 100%` from `ul` inside `#header`.
- If that somehow breaks something, another way to fix it is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#header`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any tips on how to debug these sorts of issues? Are there any tools out there that help pin these things down?

Comment: I used Firefox with the Firebug extension to find this. I kept looking further down into the tree of elements until I found the problematic `ul`. [I saw it was very wide when hovering over it](http://i.imgur.com/3uprt.png), and that it had `width: 100%`, so I toggled that rule off - problem fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll definitely apply it next time I have a layout issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your `#header ul` style specifies 100% width and 22 ems of padding on the left.

Padding applies in addition to content width, so you're making that `ul` 22 ems bigger than the width of the page, and it has to scroll over.